# Using regex to validate in JSP

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input field and I want to validate its content before passing the value further. I'm struggling with creating a proper regex though, as regex created in online editor doesn't really work with my code (actually it blocks everything).

**Desired regex behaviour:**

Only numbers and `.`, you can use `.` only once as a decimal separator, value cannot start/end with `.`, value cannot start with 0.

**My code:**

```
var valueInput = $(row).find("#value").val();
var numbers = /^[0-9.]*$/;
if( !valueInput.match(numbers) ) {
  //do something                 
}
```

`valueInput` is fine, it brins the value from the input properly. Any ideas?

**Edit.**
Thanks for your contribution, I wanted to sum up a little for people from future, looking for an answer:

**1**. Regex is not a string! I edited former code to make sure nobody's get confused, but comment to get rid of " " was crucial, thanks Pointy.

**2**. Regex I decided to use is `/^([1-9][0-9]*)+(?:\.\d+)?$/`. I realized I also need to handle case, when value has only decimal part, so it starts with 0. I didn't really want to play with regex here, so I made a trick: if valueInput start with something other than zero I validate with , else I validate with `/^[0]{1,1}\.\d{1,2}$/g`.

Comment: Could you try `parseFloat(valueInput) !== parseFloat(valueInput)` (test for NaN)? Or better, use `<input type="number" />` which will automatically validate for you.

Comment: You're creating the regular expression incorrectly. The outer double-quote characters are wrong; it should just be `/^[0-9]*$/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/[1-9](\d+)?(\.\d+[1-9])?/
```

This is the best I could come up with. If this doesn't work, do let me know.

P.S. I find [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) a nice place to test regex. Cheers.

Comment: it will not work, because this .5 will be a valid number

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
valueInput.match(/([1-9]d*)+(?:\.\d+)?$/)
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.